# UICollectionView subclass to be reused in multiple viewControllers

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, subclass, xib

I want to create a self-contained `UICollectionView` subclass (acting as its own data source and delegate) so that I could load it in different viewControllers. Here's what I have so far:

**CustomCollectionView.h**

```
@interface CustomCollectionView : UICollectionView <UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UICollectionView *collectionView;

@end
```

**CustomCollectionView.m**

```
#import "SSCalendarView.h"

@implementation SSCalendarView
@synthesize collectionView;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {

    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

    if (self) {

        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:NSStringFromClass([self class]) owner:self options:nil];

        [self registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Identifier"];

        [self addSubview:collectionView];
    }
    return self;
}

// Below are UICollectionViewDataSource and UICollectionViewDelegate methods

@end
```

**CustomCollectionView.xib**

- Contains only one view - `UICollectionView`. It's class is set to `CustomCollectionView`
- File's Owner's class is also set to `CustomCollectionView`
- File's Owner is `UICollectionView`'s delegate and data source

I understand that I have quite a few things wrong here. But perhaps we could use this as a starting point.

My questions are:

- How to implement this sub-class correctly? I want to load the view fully from xib
- To begin with, and aside from potential MVC violation (this sub-class would do it all), can a UICollectionView be its own data source and delegate?
- If above is possible, how do I correctly create an instance of this subclass to use in my view controllers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There already exists an object which you can use for this purpose - `UICollectionViewController`. This can be subclassed and added to any view controller (as a child view controller) and already contains a collection view which it is the datasource and delegate for.

The problems with your current approach are:

- As you point out, you're putting too much responsibility on one object by having a view be its own datasource and delegate
- File's owner for a xib can't be an object from within the xib. When you load the xib, the object you send to the `owner` argument is the file's owner. I've no idea what you actually end up with using the code you currently have.
- I'm not sure why you insist on using a xib anyway - what does this give you, except the headache of an extra file and the complexity of nib loading? Just create a collection view controller, you can specify the layout and register cells in the init and viewDidLoad methods.

Comment: You're right, I just needed to read some Apple documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH18-SW6)

Answer (score 0):

First of all making view to act like view controller is violation of MVC, ask you've said so - so you shouldn't probably do it.

Theoretically it's possible to force view to act as delegate & data source but I wouldn't recommend it.

If you still want to do it - just assign delegate & data source to `self`:

```
self.dataSource = self;
self.delegate = self;
```

and adopt `UICollectionViewDelegate` and `UICollectionViewDataSource` protocols in .h file

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As you see in .h I have already adopted the protocols you mentioned, and I have hooked up dataSource and delegate through IB (File's Owner, which in this case is self).